# how to get min or max value from a linked list?

Tags: python

I am trying to define a function that can get min value from a linked list of ints.

```
Given Function(not allowed to be modified):
class LN:
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

    def list_to_ll(l):
        if l == []:
           return None
        front = rear = LN(l[0])
        for v in l[1:]:
            rear.next = LN(v)
            rear = rear.next
        return front
```

Function list_to_ll convert a normal list to linked list:

```
A recursive function I am trying to define:
def get_min(ll):
    if ll == None:
       return None
    else:
       if ll.value < ll.next.value:
          return ll.value
       return get_min(ll.next)
```

For example:

```
get_min(list_to_ll([7, 3, 5, 2, 0]))--> 0
```

But my function gives me:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Please help.  Actual codes would be really appreciated.

Comment: Don't use recursion. It's cool from an academic standpoint, but there are better methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `get_min` function contains the following mistakes:

- the base case should be `if ll.next == None` and not `if ll == None`. Indeed the minimum of the empty list is not well-defined. But if `ll.next` is `None` it means that your list only contains one item. In that case the minimum of the list is the item itself, i.e. `ll.value`
- when the list has more than one element, the minimum of the list can be obtained by comparing the first element of the list (`ll.value`) **to the minimum of the remaining list** starting at `ll.next` (the tail of the list).
- finally it is a better practice to use the `is` operator to test if a Python variable is `None`.

A working code could be the following:

```
def get_min(ll):
    if ll.next is None:
        return ll.value
    else:
        tail_min = get_min(ll.next)
        if ll.value < tail_min:
            return ll.value
        else:
            return tail_min
```

If you can use the `min` function to compare two numbers, a more concise version is:

```
def get_min(ll):
    if ll.next is None:
        return ll.value
    else:
        return min(ll.value, get_min(ll.next))
```

Finally, you could raise an exception when the list is empty to warn the user of the function that he is using it in a non-applicable case:

```
def get_min(ll):
    if ll is None:
        raise ValueError("Cannot compute the minimum of the empty list.")
    elif ll.next is None:
        return ll.value
    else:
        return min(ll.value, get_min(ll.next))
```

Answer (score 5):

Implement `__iter__` for your data structure so you can iterate over it. Then you can use the regular `min()` and `max()` functions (as well as `for` loops, the `any()` and `all()` functions, `map()` and list comprehensions... etc.).

```
def __iter__(self):
    ptr = self
    while ptr is not None:
       yield ptr.value
       ptr = ptr.next
```

Comment: With __iter__ will be much easier to solve the case, but this is an program assignment from my class, I am not allowed to add anything to predefined class/functions.

Comment: That's just an awesome idea which demonstrates all the beauty of Python.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in python.
Here fist we created a circular link list and then we 
print minNode() value and maxNode() value.

```
#Represents the node of list.    
class Node:    
    def __init__(self,data):    
    self.data = data;    
        self.next = None;    

class CreateList:    
    #Declaring head and tail pointer as null.    
    def __init__(self):    
        self.head = Node(None);    
        self.tail = Node(None);    
        self.head.next = self.tail;    
        self.tail.next = self.head;  



#This function will add the new node at the end of the list.    
def add(self,data):    
    newNode = Node(data);    
    #Checks if the list is empty.    
    if self.head.data is None:    
        #If list is empty, both head and tail would point to new node.    
        self.head = newNode;    
        self.tail = newNode;    
        newNode.next = self.head;    
    else:    
        #tail will point to new node.    
        self.tail.next = newNode;    
        #New node will become new tail.    
        self.tail = newNode;    
        #Since, it is circular linked list tail will point to head.    
        self.tail.next = self.head;    

#Finds out the minimum value node in the list    
def minNode(self):    
    current = self.head;    
    #Initializing min to initial node data    
    minimum = self.head.data;    
    if(self.head == None):    
        print("List is empty");    
    else:    
        while(True):    
            #If current node's data is smaller than min    
            #Then replace value of min with current node's data    
            if(minimum > current.data):    
                minimum = current.data;    
            current= current.next;    
            if(current == self.head):    
                break;    
    print("Minimum value node in the list: "+ str(minimum));    

#Finds out the maximum value node in the list    
def maxNode(self):    
    current = self.head;    
    #Initializing max to initial node data    
    maximum = self.head.data;    
    if(self.head == None):    
        print("List is empty");    
    else:    
     while(True):    
            #If current node's data is greater than max    
            #Then replace value of max with current node's data    
            if(maximum < current.data):    
                maximum = current.data;    
            current= current.next;    
            if(current == self.head):    
                break;    
    print("Maximum value node in the list: "+ str(maximum));    

class CircularLinkedList:    
    cl = CreateList();    
    #Adds data to the list    
    cl.add(5);    
    cl.add(20);    
    cl.add(10);    
    cl.add(1);    
    #Prints the minimum value node in the list    
    cl.minNode();    
    #Prints the maximum value node in the list    
    cl.maxNode();
```

Source:[coderforevers.com](https://coderforevers.com/python/python-program/find-the-maximum-and-minimum-value-node-from-a-circular-linked-list/)